# How can I make texdoc(1) recognize its configuration file instead of the environment variable?

Tags: texdoc

I am using TeX Live 2018 on Debian GNU/Linux.
The `texdoc(1)` command's configuration files are:

```bsh
$ texdoc --files
/opt/tug/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu 3.0
Configuration files are:
    active  ~/opt/tug/texlive/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    active  /opt/tug/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
Recommended file(s) for personal settings:
    ~/opt/tug/texlive/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
```

The contents of the personal configuration file `~/opt/tug/texlive/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` is:

```bsh
$ cat ~/opt/tug/texlive/texdoc/texdoc.cnf 
viewer_pdf = (nohup ${PDFVIEWER:-xpdf} %s) 2> /dev/null &
$ echo $PDFVIEWER
mupdf
```

I expected that the texdoc(1) command will open a PDF file like that:

```bsh
(nohup mupdf /opt/tug/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/support/texdoc/texdoc.pdf) 2> /dev/null &
```

However, when I set the environment variables `$PDFVIEWER`, texdoc(1) command uses it, and ignores the personal configuration file.

```bsh
$ texdoc --debug=config texdoc
texdoc debug-version: /opt/tug/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu version 3.0
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'debug_list=config' from command line option "--debug".
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_pdf=mupdf' from environment variable "PDFVIEWER".
[...]
texdoc debug-config: Ignoring 'viewer_pdf=(nohup ${PDFVIEWER:-xpdf} %s) 2> /dev/null &' in file "~/opt/tug/texlive/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 1.
[...]
texdoc info: View command: mupdf "/opt/tug/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/support/texdoc/texdoc.pdf"
```

How can I make the `texdoc(1)` command recognize the value of `viewer_pdf` in it's personal configuration file instead of the environment variable `$PDFVIEWER`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `PDFVIEWER_texdoc'; if I do

```bsh
> export PDFVIEWER=mupdf-gl
> export PDFVIEWER_texdoc='(nohup ${PDFVIEWER:-xpdf} %s) 2> /dev/null &'
> texdoc texdoc
```

then the documentation file is opened with `mupdf-gl` (sorry, I don't have `mupdf`). If I unset `PDFVIEWER`, the file is opened with `xpdf`.

Comment: Thanks.
${PDFVIEWER:-xpdf} means that; if variable $PDFVIEWER not defined, then print "xpdf."
This is called [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)

Comment: @cmplstofB Thanks, now it should be complete.